# how to install ×32\86 using windows installer

Tags: installation, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

when I install ubuntu using windows installer it can install only ×64.how can i install ×32\86 using windows installer?

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu using Wubi?

Comment: @Anwar The term "Windows installer" indicates that the OP is using Wubi--there's no other way to install Ubuntu that can reasonably be called the "Windows installer."

Answer (score 3):

Try installing it with Wubi. If You have same problem with Wubi download manually .iso or run Wubi with `--32bit` argument.

As the [Wubi FAQ](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/faq.php) says:

> #### Can I force Wubi to download and install a 32 bit version of Ubuntu?
>
> Yes, either pre-download the appropriate 32 bit ISO manually and place it in the same folder as Wubi.exe or start Wubi with the "--32bit" argument.